# Import of CSV to SQL fails

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, import, bulk

I have a pretty simple CSV file (separator ;  Notepad++ says CR LF as line separator; UCS-2 Little Endian) that I need to daily import into SQL.
I  spent a day now making BULK INSERT or OPENROWSET work, but I fail constantly

```
BULK INSERT tt_MaterialSAPx
FROM '\\192.168.89.22\LandingZone\MAT.csv'
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2
,LASTROW = 5
--,DATAFILETYPE='native'
, FIELDTERMINator = ';'
,ROWTERMINATOR = '\r'
--,Formatfile = '\\192.168.89.22\LandingZone\formatfile.fmt'
)
```

The BULK insert Code (it doesn't import at all if I set the rowterminator to\r\n) doesn't read the characters correctly (Basically its a "blank" between each characters - UTF16 vs UFT-8?) . Furthermore it fails if I take out the LASTROW = 5 with "Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file."

The

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
BULK '\\192.168.89.22\LandingZone\MAT8.csv'
,   SINGLE_CLOB
--,Formatfile = '\\192.168.89.22\LandingZone\formatfile.fmt'
) AS DATA
```

This sticks all data into the first column and first row (so ignores field and rowterminators

Utterly frustrated: What am I missing? Or is there a third way to solve thsi?

Comment: Use `DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar'` to import UTF-16 data.

Comment: Tried - but no success

Comment: Can you provide a simplified, anonymized example file?

Comment: How would I share the example file? There is no way to add an attachment, is there?

Comment: You can add a link to Google Drive / Dropbox /etc, but you should include a small, relevant part in the text of the question.